# Any difference between aligning elements in a float div versus a regular div?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I've used "margin: 0 auto" on `<p>`, `<a>`, and `<img>` elements inside a float div but it doesn't seem to affect them. Therefore, I manually aligned them by "margin-left." It looks ok but I'd rather apply a uniform rule to all elements in the div. Thank you.

The float div:

```
#side {  
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 630px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I recommened staying away from floats as far as possible unless you're build some sort of grid system (there are lost of them out there). They cause more trouble than they're worth

Comment: You can simply use `text-align: center` on `#side`.

Comment: Post your actual HTML and a description of the desired layout in order to get specific help with what CSS will do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to centrally align all the elements (p, img, and a) inside the floated div.

Out of the 3 html elements you specified, **<p>** is a block level element, but **<img>** and **<a>** are inline elements. In order for you to use `margin: 0 auto` all the elements should have a width specified. And the width can only be specified for the block level elements.

So you can use the property `display: block` for the inline elements like `a` and `img` which will convert them to a block level element. And then you can specify the width property for all the elements inside the div (including `p, a, and img`). Once the width for all the elements are specified, now you can use `margin: 0 auto` and it should work perfectly fine.

If you want the text inside the div to be centrally aligned all the time, then you can use the css property called `text-align: center` on the div.

Answer (score 0):

The layout inside a container is not affected by whether the container is `float` or not.  That only affects where the container is positioned, not how the child elements inside the container are positioned.

The elements you are trying to use `margin` on are inline elements, not block elements.
With things like `margin: 0 auto`, the `auto` applies to block elements that would normally go full width, not inline elements which will normally be only as wide as their content.

For inline elements, you may want to use `text-align: center`, but we'd really have to see your exact HTML and the desired layout in order to know exactly what to recommend.

Comment: I thought <p> was a block element.

Comment: All set now. Thanks everyone.